# Quickly Reboot to Windows From MacOS Like You Can By Default The Other Way Around

Tags: bootcamp

Looking for a macOS equivalent to this:
[image]

When you install Windows with Bootcamp, you have this quick way to reboot to macOS. But there is no quick shortcut to do it the other way around.

I know you can hold the option key on reboot or select Windows by going into *System Preferences>General>Startup Disk>Windows>Restart* but I am looking for something quicker.

Hoping there's already an application for this out there.

Comment: What you are asking for can be done for free. However, this would require installing and configuring a third party boot manager. You would also have to configure both macOS and Windows to work with this boot manager. If you have a Mac with the T2 chip, then you would have to reduce firmware security in order to get the third party boot manger to boot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did notice an application which creates a shortcut button in macOS but I (as you mentioned) noticed it was an entire boot manager. Was hoping a simpler application that just triggers the default boot manager could be used.